# Using Selenium Web Driver to retrieve value from source

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is the source from which i need the pull the value of PackageId i.e 20981907 using selenium webdriver. I am unable to print the PackageId when i use:-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;
Object val = js.executeScript("window.setPackageId;");
```

Source:

```
<script >
/* <![CDATA[ */
try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){ }
/* ]]> */

</script>
                    <script >
/* <![CDATA[ */
var adFactory = new TiiAdFactory(adConfig, "/scoop");
adFactory.setArticleId("20999784");
**adFactory.setPackageId("20981907");**  /* I need this value to be printed in eclipse console*/
adFactory.setChannel("");
adFactory.setSubchannel("scoop");
adFactory.setContentPage();
adFactory.setContentType("article");
adFactory.setParam("page", "");
adFactory.setParam("franc", "Scoop");
adFactory.setParam("subj", new Array("peoplescoop"));
adFactory.setParam("celeb", new Array("lindsaylohan"));
adFactory.setParam("sourc", source);
adFactory.setParam("appids", PEOPLE.appIds);
/* ]]> */

</script>
                    <script >
/* <![CDATA[ */
PEOPLE.News.articledate = '04-12-2016';
/* ]]> */

</script>
                    <script >
/* <![CDATA[ */
PEOPLE.adPageBannerIsEnabled=false;PEOPLE.enableStickyNav = true; PEOPLE.adHeaderPromotionIsEnabled = true;
/* ]]> */
</script>
                        <script src="/people/static/j/package/scoop/main.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: What language is this?  This context seems to hint at java, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at here.  I would suggest adding a tag for the specific language whose selenium bindings you're using.  More information is better because it gives us a better idea what you're situation is.  Are there errors you get, or is the output simply incorrect?  Do you have a snippet of the selenium code you're trying to run?  How about other things you've tried and how you tried them?

Comment: Are you trying to capture from script tag ..best way I think would be get the page source and then read from substring setPackageId

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what `TiiAdFactory` is, but it's definitely wrong to use `window` instead of the actual instance. **Assuming** the class does have a getter, this will return the value for the relevant instance:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dr;
Object val = js.executeScript("return adFactory.getPackageId();");
```

I'm also assuming you're using Selenium because you're trying to pull a live value from an interactive user session. If that weren't true, you could of course just scrape the value from the JavaScript source using any old HTTP library.